# A better Reference than Andre Weil's Basic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I want to get a feel for Adeles. I have been suggested to read the first 4 chapters of Andre Weil's Basic Number Theory. I am very confused by the writing style and conventions (like a field need not be commutative) used in the book. Is there any other suitable reference? I find Ramakrishnan and Valenza's Fourier Analysis on Number fields easy to read. But, I am afraid the content is not the same.

Comment: See this link<http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53800/is-there-any-book-explaining-in-detail-the-book-basic-number-theory-by-andre-w>

Answer (score 1):

A great reference on the subject is the book "Class Field Theory" of Joürgen Neurkirch.